# Why isn't admin_notices displaying my text? [Simple Plugin, Beginner]

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin

Here is some code that is the result of four days of studying Wordpress and PHP. Unfortunately, it's not working the way it's supposed to. Nothing displays at the admin_notices bar.

Originally, I thought it was the **$filename = is_plugin_active($filename) ? "$filename: Active" : "$filename: Disabled";** line, but that was not the problem. What say you?

```
function show_names()
{                  
  $paths = array();

  foreach (glob("*/plugins/*") as $filename) {                                                                                                          
    $filename = is_plugin_active($filename) ? "$filename: Active" : "$filename: Disabled";
    $filename = str_replace('wp-content/plugins/', '', $filename);
    $paths[] = $filename;   
    }

  $paths = implode("---", $paths);
  echo $paths;
}

add_action("admin_notices", "show_names");
```

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump($paths);` shows that the your $paths variable is an empty string. It's not showing anything because there is nothing to show.

Since you seem like you're trying to find all the plugins, you should have a look at [`get_plugins`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins). `glob` is going to be relative to the current working directory (with will vary depending on your server setup) and `is_plugin_active` active takes a [`plugin_basename`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename).

`get_plugins` will return an associative array with the plugin basenames as keys as the file header data as the values (in an array).

A few other notes:

`admin_notices` does not automagically format your notices to look pretty. You can wrap it your notice with `<div class="error">` or `<div class="updated">` to do that.

Always give your functions a unique prefix or put them in a [namespace](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/66484/6035) (PHP 5.3+ only).

Revised code:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_notices', 'wpse72637_show_names');
function wpse72637_show_names()
{                  
    $paths = array();

    foreach(get_plugins() as $p_basename => $plugin)
    {
        $paths[] = "{$plugin['Name']}: " .
            (is_plugin_active($p_basename) ? 'Active' : 'Disabled');
    }

    echo '<div class="updated"><p>', implode(' --- ', $paths), '<p></div>';
}
```

Comment: Great fix, sir. Didn't even know that get_plugins existed - that'll be handy for my next project. Out of curiosity, is there a way to print the output of functions (like var_dump) to a blank page? I'd like to do that so debugging is a little cleaner.

Comment: You can do something like this: `var_dump(some_func()); die;` or use `var_export` (`die(var_export(some_func()));`). Either works and will kill execution so you can study what's going on. Alternatively you could use something [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

Comment: Sir, this is a +1 from me.