# Namespaces in WordPress - How do I initiate the main class?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, oop

I have very basic knowledge of OOP in PHP and am trying to learn to use namespaces in WordPress plugins. Followed some instructions from these 2 sources:

1. [WPSE 63668](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63668/autoloading-namespaces-in-wordpress-plugins-themes-can-it-work)
2. [Paulund](http://www.paulund.co.uk/namespacing-autoloaders-wordpress-plugins)

This is how my current code looks:

**Root Folder: plugins/oowp**

**File: oowp/bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: OOWP
*/
require_once('autoload.php');
```

**File: oowp/autoload.php**

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('autoload_function');
function autoload_function( $classname )
{
    $class = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, str_replace( '_', '-', strtolower($classname) ) );

    // create the actual filepath
    $filePath = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filePath))
    {
        // require once on the file
        require_once $filePath;
    }
}
```

**File: oowp/objects/custom-objects.php**

```
<?php

namespace oowp\objects;

class Custom_Objects {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array($this, 'trial'));
    }

    public function trial() {
        echo 'Works';
    }
}
```

How and where do I initiate this class? Do I need to write another class which starts the processing? I tried creating the instance of the `custom-objects` class in the file itself but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it a try like so:

**File: oowp/bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: OOWP
*/

require_once( 'autoload.php' );

use oowp\objects\Custom_Objects;

new Custom_Objects;
```

Comment: You're great! It works! So if I want to call functions from multiple classes, I should initiate them in `bootstrap.php`? Any tips to improve my setup and make it better?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by _So if I want to call functions from multiple classes, I should initiate them in bootstrap.php?_ You have to make sure you have a reference to what class you wish to have access to by using the 'use' operator. For a lot of more information you can browse [the online manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: Thanks again. I will use only the class which serves as an entry to my code's execution.