# Implementing namespaces in plugin template

Tags: plugin-development, namespace

To get with the time and improve my coding practices, I'm starting to implementing [namespaces](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) in my own plugins moving forward since there are some advantages, [such as eliminating ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5393108/6579923).

I found a [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/193997/98212) to help me set up my plugin template which worked for me. However, I've since modified it slightly. This is my setup:

In `wp-plugin-template/wp-plugin-template.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WP Plugin Template
 */
# If accessed directly, exit
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
# Call the autoloader
require_once( 'autoloader.php' );

use PluginTemplate\admin\Plugin_Meta;
new Plugin_Meta;
```

In `wp-plugin-template/autoloader.php`:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register( 'autoload_function' );
function autoload_function( $classname ) {
    $class = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, str_replace( '_', '-', strtolower($classname) ) );
    # Create the actual file-path
    $path = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';
    # Check if the file exists
    if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
        # Require once on the file
        require_once $path;
    }
}
```

In `wp-plugin-template/admin/plugin-meta.php`:

```
<?php
namespace PluginTemplate\admin;
class Plugin_Meta {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array($this, 'test' ) );
    }

    public function test() {
        echo 'It works!';
    }
}
```

When I try to activate the plugin template for testing, I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Class `PluginTemplate\admin\Plugin_Meta` not found in `wp-content/plugins/wp-plugin-template/wp-plugin-template.php` on *line 11*

In this case, line 11 is:

```
new Plugin_Meta;
```

I think this is due to me having the namespace named `PluginTemplate`? What am I doing wrong? Just to reiterate, [the previous question that I mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/193997/98212) worked for me before I started to rename my files and directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your Autoloader set-up. You need to convert your Camelcase namespacese to dashes for locating files as per your current folder structure.

I have added convert function and updated your autoloader function.

In `wp-plugin-template/autoloader.php`:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register( 'autoload_function' );
function autoload_function( $classname ) {
    $class = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, str_replace( '_', '-', strtolower(convert($classname)) ) );
    # Create the actual file-path
    $path = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';
    # Check if the file exists
    if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
        # Require once on the file
        require_once $path;
    }
}

function convert($class){
    $class = preg_replace('#([A-Z\d]+)([A-Z][a-z])#','\1_\2', $class);
    $class = preg_replace('#([a-z\d])([A-Z])#', '\1_\2', $class);
    return $class;
}
```

Also you have to update your top level namespace to `WpPluginTemplate` in both `wp-plugin-template.php` and `admin/plugin-meta.php` as you are using wp-plugin-template as your plugin folder name.

UPDATE:

When autoloader tries to find `Plugin_Meta` class, it will look into YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR/wp-plugin-template/admin/plugin-meta.php

In `wp-plugin-template.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WP Plugin Template
 */
# If accessed directly, exit
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
# Call the autoloader
require_once( 'autoloader.php' );

use WpPluginTemplate\admin\Plugin_Meta;
new Plugin_Meta;
```

In `wp-plugin-template/admin/plugin-meta.php`

```
<?php
namespace WpPluginTemplate\admin;
class Plugin_Meta {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array($this, 'test' ) );
    }

    public function test() {
        echo 'It works!';
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So it's the autoloader. I think what's throwing it off is that my plugin folder has dashes (`wp-plugin-template`) whereas the one from [the example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/193997/98212) doesn't (`oowp`). I updated my autoloader to the code that you provides and the namespaces to `WpPluginTemplate`, but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check code edits.I added all files with update. Make sure you use exact same code as I pasted, I have tested this on WP install and plugin is activated, No Errors. Key is using correct namesapces. If still throws error try to echo path autholoader uses to look for your included files.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see why it didn't work for me with your initial answer, I also replaced `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` with `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` from @birgire's answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Just some additional note about your autoloader:*

If the `$classname` input is `PluginTemplate\admin\Plugin_Meta` then the `$path` becomes

```
/full/path/to/wp-content/plugins/plugintemplate/admin/plugin-meta.php
```

and this file doesn't exists and the `Plugin_Meta` class definition isn't loaded.

It's also [not recommended](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants) to use the `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`   constant directly, there are alternatives, like `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`.

There are more complete autoloaders out there, e.g. the [generated autoloader in  Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That makes much more sense when you lay it out that way. I used your alternative of `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` along with @CSabhar's answer, but it seems to not work unless I use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` instead. Why's that? Also, I checked out the link that you provided, but I don't entirely understand how to generate the autoloader using Composer since I don't have any experience using it. May you please elaborate?

Comment: I think if `$path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . $class . '.php';` in your example and if you move `admin/` under the `plugintemplate/` directory, then your simple autoloader should work. One can map the class names to the directory structure, in various ways. There are some standards like the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). With Composer, one can define it in the `composer.json` file. There are  some [examples here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload). @EthanJinksO'Sullivan