# worldpay class not working with namespace in WordPress

Tags: plugins, namespace

I am trying to create Worldpay gateway with help of Worldpay library and my own extending code. Here is my code which I tried and failed to work on.

```
require_once('init.php');

use lib\Worldpay;

if($_POST == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    //Form Submit Actions, Here i have called Worldpay class to create object.
 $worldpay = new Worldpay('Key');   //line no:  25
}  ?>
<script src="https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js"></script>
<form  action="" method="post"> 


</form>
```

I have tried to find similar question and answer. I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193997/namespaces-in-wordpress-how-do-i-initiate-the-main-class). Eventhough i can't make it work, when form is submitted to the same page. Here is the error message how it looks like.

> Fatal error: Class 'lib\Worldpay' not found in /var/www/wp/kvcodes/wp-content/plugins/kvcodes-worldpay/WorldPay.php on line 25

How do I fix this issue, when form is submitted.

Comment: The error indicates that the lib\Worldpay class is not included correctly - via include, require or autoloading - you need to ensure that library is available.

Comment: its been 3 years ago i asked this question, and it was fixed and i forget the solution as well. but it was fixed. thank you for the contribution even after 3 years, you have an intention to comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
require_once(__DIR__ .'/init.php');
```

Comment: Still I am getting the same error. I Think i am missing something here or problem with namespace

Comment: does `init.php` includes `namespace` ?

Comment: no, but the required files inside init has this namespace `Worldpay`.  Any idea, How to use namespace here in my plugin file.

Comment: AFAIK, while using `use` command, there should be present `namespace` somewhere in the top. However, as that in StackOverflow, because it not related to wp directly, but Namespacing/classes.

Comment: Can you give me an example.?

Comment: You can use "use" without a defined namespace in the file, it simply imports the class, which might come from any Namespace.