# Allow SVG in WP step by step

Tags: images, wp-admin, security, svg

I'm not strong in WP programming, bu I try to understand what to do to enable SVG in my site. I found that in need to add function below to `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Add SVG capabilities
 */
function wpcontent_svg_mime_type( $mimes = array() ) {
  $mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpcontent_svg_mime_type' );
```

`wpcontent` should be replaced with namespace. But how to know what is my WP namespace?

Add lines below to `.htaccess` file after the line, `#End WordPress`:

```
# Add SVG Mime Types
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

Is anything else I shoud do?

UPD. After this procedure iI have following:

Now I can upload files to Media, but no preview. And when I do insert nothing happens - no new picture.

How to solve this?

Comment: Your namespace, or rather your prefix, is whatever you choose it to be. Don't call it a namespace though, namespaces are something different in PHP. E.g. I prefix my functions with `tomjn_`, but I could have prefixed with `moomins_` or `cup_of_tea_`, so long as they're unique to my code it doesn't matter

Comment: I would also argue your question has been answered, and that your preview and thumbnail issue should be a second/new question

Comment: Relevant: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157480/ways-to-handle-svg-rendering-in-wordpress?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code to my functions.php works great for me. No need to modify the .htaccess file at all.

```
function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
   $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
   return $mimes;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );
```

This allows me to upload and display SVG images without any issues.

Comment: Got error after adding add_filter. Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in /home/.../wp-includes/functions.php on line 32

Comment: Where did you put the code? You shouldn't be modify WordPress core

Comment: @vico As Tom pointed out, it looks like you've put the code in Wordpress core. When I say "functions.php", I'm referring to the current Theme's "functions.php" file.

Answer (score 1):

> But how to know what is my WP namespace?

namespacing a function, in WP land, just means prefixing it with something that makes it more unique and unlikely to conflict with anything else. Generally that means you do both a "vendor" and a "package". For instance, if I'm building a plugin, my function upload mimes function might be...

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'chrisguitarguy_pluginname_mimes');
function chrisguitarguy_pluginname_mimes($mimes)
{
    // ...
}
```

Where `chrisguitarguy` is my "vendor" name and `pluginname` is the package. You can do this [PHP namespaces](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63668/autoloading-namespaces-in-wordpress-plugins-themes-can-it-work) as well.

```
namespace Chrisguitarguy\PluginName;

add_action('upload_mimes', __NAMESPACE__.'\\mimes');
function mimes($mimes)
{
    // ...
}
```

> Is anything else I shoud do?

Nope, what you have is perfect. You may want to specify that svgz is gzipped in your `.htaccess`.

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
// http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Newer versions of apache might include this config by default?

Comment: Now I can upload files to Media, but no preview. And when I do insert nothing happens - no new picture.